# Static final in supertype

Tags: java, static, final, super, supertype

Why is it that even if you have declared a private static final variable, a color - defaultC, let's say - then you still cannot use `this.defaultC` in the super constructor (i.e. you can only use `super(defaultC)` and not `super(this.defaultC`) even though it is equivalent to simply `defaultC`.

I was simply trying to extend a Tile class to a Wall class and the Wall class I stored all of the necessary `private static final` variables for all walls (such as their width and height, another int and the default color), and the Tile class already has some of the variables (but they are `protected` not `private`). I didn't want the warning `Field hides another field` to pop up (because there Tile.java and Wall.java have the same names for many variables), so I used `this.` for my private static final variables, and there were errors galore.

It's not particularly troubling (as I simply have a few warnings), but I was simply wondering why. I am guessing that the compiler simply doesn't like it because you cannot reference `this` before the supertype, but there are still exactly the same. Has such a feature not been added yet that overlooks such a thing or is there another reason I cannot see that you cannot use `super(this.PRIVATE_STATIC_FINAL_VARIABLE);`?

Comment: code gives better understanding than a long description of your problem.

Comment: Use `MyClass.PRIVATE_STATIC_FINAL_VARIABLE` not `this.PRIVATE_STATIC_FINAL_VARIABLE`

Comment: Thanks `MyClass` works, but I could have sworn that `this` is the same thing as `MyClass`. I guess they are not the same, though. If `this.VAR` doesn't specifically reference that static variable `VAR`, then what exactly does it do? I know you can reference any variable that isn't private and static with `this` so it seems kind of weird that it isn't the same thing as `MyClass.VAR`.

Comment: Thanks for down votes for something that I was not aware of! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here we have two things to know,

1. what is the meaning of `static` keyword.
2. what is the meaning of `this` keyword
3. what is a `constructor`

in java, there are two types, `class` and `instance of an class`. We can use a class without creating an instance of it, or after creating a instance of the class itself.

`object` is an instance of a `class`.

The keyword `static` is used with the class. `this` is used with instances of class. And `this` keyword refers the `instance of the class` it is used within.

An `instance of an class`(`object`) is created after calling the class's `constructor`. We can use keyword `this` only after creating an instance of class (inside the object).

As the constructor method is called before creating the instance of the class, We can't use `this` keyword inside a constructor. That's why you got an error in `super(this.defaultC)` but not in `super(defaultC)`

And you can't use `this` keyword inside constructor for `PRIVATE_STATIC_FINAL_VARIABLE` as well.

But you are allowed to use `PRIVATE_STATIC_FINAL_VARIABLE` without using `this` 
`i.e. super(PRIVATE_STATIC_FINAL_VARIABLE)`

Comment: This is wrong. `instance` is a synonym of `object`. You're probably referring to a _class_, as in **instance of a class**.

Answer (score 7):

A static variable does not belong to any instance of an object.  The `this` keyword should refer to an instance of an object and variables used within.  While you can use the `this` keyword to access static variables, you should not.

Also, a variable marked private in a super class cannot be accessed within a child class.

To reference a variable declared in a super class from a child class using the `this` keyword, that variable must be declared `protected` or `public`.

Comment: It can be `static`. If it's visible, you can (shouldn't but can) access it through `this`, even if it is `static`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ah! So you can, I've corrected my answer.

Comment: But not necessarily in the `super(..)` invocation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to tie the static final variable to the class you're in when passing it to super.  I believe you can do this by doing something like `super(SubClass.PRIVATE_STATIC_FINAL_VARIABLE);`

Comment: I pretty much said what Sam Yonnou said.  I didn't see his post before posting my answer, though.